# Parsing PDF font operator missing

Tags: parsing, pdf, fonts, cgpdf, cgpdfscanner

I'm parsing a PDF file and it seems that a Tf operator is missing. I can see, on PDF readers like *Acrobat reader* or *Preview*, that the font changes. But during the parse I don't have the Tf operator. I still have the ET operator that marks the ending of the previous text block and BT operator for the beginning of the new one. I also have text showing operator Tj & co.

Just to be clear, I do have Tf operators, but just in one place it should be there, it isn't.

The PDF reference states :

> There is no initial value for either font or size; they must be
>   specified explicitly by using Tf before any text is shown.

I don't understand why if I don't have Tf operator, how those readers can render the text correctly ?

Does someone know where the problem could come from ?

Comment: Please share the PDF in question (or at least the content stream you are talking about). Furthermore, please be aware that PDF viewers have a tendency to try and display even invalid PDFs; in doing so they have to go beyond the specification. Probably you are running into such a situation.

Comment: @mkl I was wondering that too. I can't share the pdf or the logs because I'm not allowed to do so. Anyway, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK text state is part of graphics state so if you have a `Q` operator somewhere there then that would explain the font changing (it would restore the state saved by previous `q` operator).

Also, the graphics state operator `gs` could cause the change of font.

Comment: Indeed, I have q and Q operators. Thank you for your answer.